# Tried to clear trash and everything go removed!

Tags: undelete

I found a command online to clear the trash for you because I wanted to clear a file without doing it throught GUI. The command is `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*` . I called it and saw the folder on my right monitor disapear. I looked on the left monitor to see everything gone. I looked up recovery tools for ubuntu and found `photorec` . I used it and it said it recovered 200 files but none are there. **EVERYTHING** from my home directory is gone as well as Documents downloads, etc. How can I recover this? I had many important things I didn't back up.

Comment: Is it possible you accidentally put a space between `~` and `/`, or between `/` and `.`, or between the last `/` and `*`? Whatever happened...it sounds like `extundelete` may help. See [How to recover deleted files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: `I had many important things I didn't back up.` Now you know better.

Comment: Also a side note, running user specific commands (I.E removing files from your home folder) really shouldn't be ran with `sudo` as it can be very dangerous. If you made mistake and included `/` in the `rm` command you'd remove your whole system instead of just your home folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `sudo testdisk` in terminal.
2. Unless you want a log file of the operations, choose `No Log` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Hard drives are shown, it is possible to distinguish them with the size and the model name. Go on the hard drive you want to analyse and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. You are asked for what is the partition table, for a normal PC it should be Intel. EFI GPT is for recent Apple Macs, Mac is for old PPC Mac. Choose the right one and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Choose Analyse and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Testdisk shows the current partitions, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to do a **Quick Search**
7. Choose the partition that contains the files you want to recover and press the letter <kbd>P</kbd>. If you can't identify what is the right partition, you can try one. At any time your can come back to this menu by pressing the letter <kbd>Q</kbd>
8. You are now in the directory tree (files and folders) of the partition! Each line starting with `d` letter is a folder, each line starting with a hyphen (`-`) is a file. Red lines are files/folders that have been deleted. You can move in files and folders with arrow keys on the keyboard, you can open a folder by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you can go to the parent folder by going on the double dot (`..`) and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The location where you are is always shown at the top near the word Directory. You can recover a file or a folder at any time by pressing <kbd>C</kbd>.
9. The first time you will press <kbd>C</kbd>, you will be asked where to copy the files. You have to move up to the destination folder and press <kbd>C</kbd>. For that purpose, you need to know the path of that folder. Once done, testdisk confirms you if the operation succeeded of failed, completely or partially. If you copy a large amount of files, be patient and wait for the transfer even if nothing happens on the screen.
10. You're done!

    ---

Source: http://computriks.com/en/recover-file-testdisk